# ContextAPI useContext method returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

```
import Nav from "./components/Nav";
import Container from "./components/Container";
import Pagination from "./components/Pagination";
import StatesProvider from "./components/StatesProvider";
import { useStateManagerContext } from "./components/StatesProvider";
export default function App() {

    const {stepVal,previousPage,nextPage,validateCurrentStep} = useStateManagerContext();




    console.log(stepVal);
    return (
        <StatesProvider>
            <Container>
                <Nav></Nav>
                <div
                    className="w-[95%] min-h-1/2 bg-white rounded-xl
                 z-10 absolute border-2 border-solid border-gray-300
                  place-self-center top-28 p-6 pb-8 flex flex-col justify-center
                   lg:relative llg:col-span-3 lg:row-span-3 lg:border-none
                    lg:h-full lg:top-0"
                >
                    <form>
                        <Pagination order={stepVal}></Pagination>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <button
                    id="go-back"
                    className={
                        `self-start top-[93%] h-12 w-28 rounded-xl
                     text-gray-400 absolute font-bold tracking-widest ml-[2.5%] 
                    place-self-start lg:self-end mb-2 lg:top-0 lg:mr-0 lg:mb-2 
                    lg:relative lg:row-start-4 lg:row-end-5 lg:col-start-2 
                    lg:col-end-3 ` + (stepVal === 0 ? "hidden" : "")
                    }
                    onClick={previousPage}
                >
                    Go back
                </button>

                <button
                    id="next-step"
                    className={
                        `bg-dif-blue self-end top-[92%] h-12 w-28 
                    rounded-xl text-white absolute font-bold mr-[3%]
                     place-self-end lg:top-0 lg:mr-[50%] lg:mb-2 lg:relative 
                     lg:row-start-4 lg:row-end-5 lg:col-start-4 lg:col-end-5` +
                        (stepVal === 4 ? "hidden" : "")
                    }
                    onClick={() => {
                        const isValidated = validateCurrentStep();
                        nextPage(isValidated);
                    }}
                >
                    {stepVal === 3 ? "Confirm" : "Next Step"}
                </button>
            </Container>
        </StatesProvider>
    );
}
```

App.js

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
const StatesContext = createContext();

let validateCurrentStep, form, nextPage, previousPage;

const StatesProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [stepVal, setStepVal] = useState(0);
    const [billingType, setBillingType] = useState("monthly");
    const [stateList, setStateList] = useState([true, true, true, true]);
    const [chosenSub, setChosenSub] = useState(null);
    const {
        register,
        trigger,
        formState: { errors },
    } = useForm();
    nextPage = (validated) => {
        validated.then((data) => (data ? setStepVal(stepVal + 1) : null));
    };
    previousPage = () => {
        setStepVal(stepVal - 1);
    };
    validateCurrentStep = async () => {
        let validationList = [];
        let isValidated = true;
        if (stepVal === 0) {
            validationList = ["fullName", "email", "phone"];
        } else if (stepVal === 1) validationList = ["", "", "", "subscription"];
        const stateListClone = [...stateList];

        for (let i = 0; i < validationList.length; i++) {
            const promise = await form.trigger(validationList[i]);
            isValidated = promise;
            stateListClone[i] = promise;
        }
        setStateList(stateListClone);
        return isValidated;
    };
    return (
        <StatesContext.Provider
            value={{
                stepVal,
                setStepVal,
                billingType,
                setBillingType,
                stateList,
                setStateList,
                chosenSub,
                setChosenSub,
                form: { register, trigger, formState: { errors } },
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </StatesContext.Provider>
    );
};
export default {StatesProvider,nextPage,previousPage,validateCurrentStep};

export const useStateManagerContext = () => useContext(StatesContext);
```

StatesProvider.js
I get error of `Cannot destructure property 'stepVal' of '(0 , _components_StatesProvider__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.useStateManagerContext)(...)' as it is undefined. TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'stepVal' of '(0 , _components_StatesProvider__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.useStateManagerContext)(...)' as it is undefined.`
I made it work on a small application, i tried to make it the same but even though i did(probably i missed it) and I couldn't see it.Can you please explain me why i am getting undefined value of stepVal?
If you can explain the reason i get the undefined i would appreciate it so much! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you have created the context correctly and app.js code is fine too exept for one mistake, you have incorrectly wrapped the StatesProvider.
The Provider values are only available to its children, you App component is not the child of StateProvider.

You should do something like this.

```
export default function App() {

    return (
        <StatesProvider>
            <ChildComponent />
        </StatesProvider>
      )
```

and in the child-component.js file

```
export default function ChildComponent() {
    const { stepVal } = useStateManagerContext();
    return (
          ...
          <button>
          {stepVal}
          </button>
          ...
        )
```

You can access all values from the context here.